# Upgrading EE 2.11.9 to 3.5.10 - unable to update to Tagger 4.0.0 from DevDemon

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-tagger, tagger

I'm trying to upgrade a site from EE2.11.9 to 3.5.10 and during the process, upgrading DevDemon's Tagger from v3.2.1 to 4.0.0 but getting this issue when trying to upgrade:

Exception Caught No such method filter. ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Mixin/Manager.php:143

I have seen that other folks also have this problem:
[Upgrading EE 2.11.9 to 3.5.6 - problems updating Tagger from DevDemon](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/39299/upgrading-ee-2-11-9-to-3-5-6-problems-updating-tagger-from-devdemon)

Please help DevDemon

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue just by uninstalling the addon and installing it again in admin panel. Without upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

This is really old, but for those who need to upgrade sites running EE2 to newer versions with Tagger, this worked for me.

**Note: uninstalling Tagger and reinstalling it from the Add-on Manager does work, but it will erase all of your existing tags. To prevent this from happening, follow the steps below.**

This is assuming Tagger is on version 3.2.1. Right after moving the EE3 files over and before running the update step, copy over the files for Tagger 4.0.0.

In tagger/upd.tagger.php, there is this code:

```
$module = $module = ee('Model')->make('Module', array(
    'module_name', ucfirst($this->module_name),
)->first();
```

Update these lines to the following:

```
$module = ee('Model')->make('Module', array(
    'module_name', ucfirst($this->module_name),
));
```

After the EE update step, go to the Add-On Manager and click "Update to 4.0.0" next to Tagger in the list.